# Как установить php5, имея уже установленную php7?

Tags: linux, веб-сервер

Начал ставить сервер по этому [руководству](http://senokosov.info/lamp/install-lamp) все идет хорошо, но вот только ни как не могу установить модуль php5. У меня Linux 16, а в нём php7.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Если хотите несколько версий - https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew это менеджер версий php. Возможно поможет

Comment: @UserName, вообщем сегодня опять в бой, но уже в этот раз ставлю линукс 14 потом пойду по этой инстркуции - http://senokosov.info/lamp/install-lamp Хочу сначала на простеньком научится а потом уже как пойму как все устроенно пойду дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял у вас  Linux Mint 16.
   Попробуйте данную команду для графической установки LAMP

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

UPD:  Нашел видео на YouTube, вероятно так будет удобнее

Ссылка : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNpyEEW6No8

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас гляну.

Comment: пишет команда не найдена.

Comment: Значит необходимо установить tasksel `sudo apt-get install tasksel`

Comment: Спасибо, эта команда для установки tasksel, возьму себе на заметку.